# Overload in web application server

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, gvnix

I have created a web application to manage a veterinary clinic with **Spring Roo** and **Gvnix** tools.
I created the database with the tables *veterinary* , *owners*, *pets*, *dating*, all these tables relate to **1 to many** , except the table *treatments* and *medicines* that relate **many to many**, these 2 tables above include an intermediate table , called _treatment_med_ which serves to interact between them , use database manager **MySQL workbench** and **MYSQL Server**  , everything works perfect , from the web application forms I **create, update and delete** *owners*, *pets*, *veterinarians*, *dating*, *medications* but when I try to create more than 2 records on table treatments doing a multiple selection in drugs that have related to the table through treatments a tag **jspx**.

```
<field:select field="Med"  id="c_com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Tratamiento_Med" itemValue="id" items="${medicamentoses}" multiple="true" path="/medicamentoses" z="+hr+pOBWxfr2whYp+joa+OMxAHk="/>
```

The application gives me an error without detail of because and I drop by full

I see process from the task manager of Windows with **Java (TM) platform SE Binary name** (java.exe) soars to more than **+1,800 KB** (private working space), which makes the web application **fall**.

Problem in this part of code in the **AspectJ class** for persistence of the Gvnix with the name.

privileged aspect TratamientoBatchService_Roo_GvNIXJpaBatch {

I think that the error is here.

```
@Transactional
public void TratamientoBatchService.create(List<Tratamiento> tratamientoes) {
for( Tratamiento tratamiento : tratamientoes) {
    tratamiento.persist();
}
}
```

This is error showing me the IntelliJ IDE console:

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:272)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendFieldSeparator(ToStringStyle.java:1503)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendFieldEnd(ToStringStyle.java:1526)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.append(ToStringStyle.java:439)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.append(ToStringBuilder.java:848)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.appendFieldsIn(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:522)  
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:683)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:282) 
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:145) 
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Citas_Roo_ToString.ajc$interMethod$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Citas_Roo_ToString$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Citas$toString(Citas_Roo_ToString.aj:13)
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Citas.toString(Citas.java:1)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendDetail(ToStringStyle.java:586)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.appendInternal(ToStringStyle.java:550)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle.append(ToStringStyle.java:436)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.append(ToStringBuilder.java:848)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.appendFieldsIn(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:522)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:683)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:282)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(ReflectionToStringBuilder.java:145)
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento_Roo_ToString.ajc$interMethod$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Tratamiento_Roo_ToString$com_clinicaveterinaria_dam_domain_Tratamiento$toString(Tratamiento_Roo_ToString.aj:13)
at com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento.toString(Tratamiento.java:1)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:317)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

I've tried to configure the Maven server from the IDE IntelliJ IDEA to increase the amount of memory that can withstand through "- Xmx512m - XX:MaxPermSize = 128 m" but the problem cannot be solved.

This is my class Java : **Tratamiento.java**

```
package com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Tratamiento {

/**
 */
@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 100)
private String Codigo;
/**
 */
@Size(min = 3, max = 250)
private String AnalisisClinicos;

/**
 */
@Size(min = 3, max = 250)
private String Medicamentos;

/**
 */
private double Coste;

/**
 */
@Size(min = 3, max = 250)
private String Diagnostico;

/**
 */
@Size(min = 3, max = 250)
private String MotivoIngreso;

/**
 */
@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
private Date FechaComienzoTratamiento;

/**
 */
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
private Date FechaFinTratamiento;

/**
 */
@ManyToOne
private Citas citas;

/**
 */
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Medicamentos> Med = new HashSet<Medicamentos>();


public static List<Tratamiento> findTratamientoXDueño(int idUsr) {
    if (idUsr <= 0 /*mas comprobaciones*/) return null;
    Query query = entityManager().createNativeQuery(
            " SELECT t.* FROM tratamiento t " +
                    " INNER JOIN citas c ON c.id = t.citas " +
                    " INNER JOIN mascota m ON m.id = c.mascotas " +
                    " WHERE m.duenio = (:idUsr)"
            , Tratamiento.class).setParameter("idUsr", idUsr);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public static List<Tratamiento> findTratamientoXVeterinario(int idUsr) {
    if (idUsr <= 0 /*mas comprobaciones*/) return null;
    Query query = entityManager().createNativeQuery(
            " SELECT t.* FROM tratamiento t " +
                    " INNER JOIN citas c ON c.id = t.citas " +
                    " WHERE c.veterinarios = (:idUsr)"
            , Tratamiento.class).setParameter("idUsr", idUsr);
    return query.getResultList();
}
}
```

Thank you by the help , i am doing the final course project.
I am using MVC **(Model–view–controller)**.
Sorry , my english is very bad.

Comment: Can you post the `Tratamiento` class?

Comment: Yes , now I put the code.

Comment: What you have there is an OutOfMemoryError. It is caused by a memory leak in your app. But the stack trace is completely irrelevant: the error could have happened anywhere else. You need to use a profiler, or carful code analysis, to understand why the memory used by the app keeps growing and growing. You're probably keeping objects in a collection or map, and never clearing it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is **override** the method **toString**.

```
package com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain;

import com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

privileged aspect Tratamiento_Roo_ToString {
public String Tratamiento.toString() {
return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
}    
}
```

New method toString.

```
 package com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain;

import com.clinicaveterinaria.dam.domain.Tratamiento;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

privileged aspect Tratamiento_Roo_ToString {

public String Tratamiento.toString() {
return "";
  }
}
```

Now the app web doesn´t fall

Comment: you *Shouldn't* modify _.aj_ files because it's used by Spring Roo and *will override this change* next time you start the _console_. The right way to solve your problem is definie `toString` inside `Tratamiento.java`. Spring Roo detects that this method is declared already on `.java` file and *will not regenerate* it.

Comment: See _.aj_ files header: `// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY SPRING ROO.
// You may push code into the target .java compilation unit if you wish to edit any member(s)`